# Change image size in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to change the height of an image "red check" which is placed on a worksheet however this leads to an error. Any ideas what's wrong here?

```
Sheet1.Shapes("red_check").ShapeRange.Height = 0
```

Comment: what's the error? Is it `red check` or `red_check`?

Comment: Why not do: `Sheet1.Shapes("red_check").Height = 0` ?

Comment: You're welcome. I added a full answer to expand on this a bit more for anyone else who comes across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
       Shapes("red_check")
```

this returns a `Shape` object ([check out its members on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193908(v=office.14).aspx)). Therefore, you can simply do the following:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("red_check").Height = 0
```

in order to set your shape's `Height` property. You can similarly set `Width`, etc.